# OpenGL glBegin ... glEnd

Tags: c++, opengl

I wanted to know how badly my games will be affected by using `glBegin` and whatnot instead of GLSL and VBOs and VAOs and all that. They just look **so** difficult and ridiculous to achieve what I can do easier. What will the effect of my choices be?

Comment: I’ve edited your question a little bit. For future reference, Stack Overflow is pretty strict—it helps to avoid anything in your question that isn’t directly on-topic, such as swearing or even “thank you”. That strictness might seem oppressive, but it does help encourage more useful questions and answers, so everyone ultimately benefits.

Comment: As both games and OpenGL matures, it tends to be less a tool for game developers and more a tool for game engine writers, what in turn are to be used by game developers. Games complexity are going up, while OpenGL abstractions are going down, so if What you want is to make games, maybe you should look into a higher level tool, like [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Badly.

The direct mode API with `glBegin()` and `glEnd()` is deprecated, largely for performance reasons. It doesn’t really support data parallelism, and relies heavily on the CPU—requiring at least one function call per vertex. That adds up quickly.

The direct mode API might be simpler and more pleasant for you to use in small projects, but using VBOs scales better, both in terms of performance and maintainability. It’s much easier to manage data than it is to manage state.

Also, learning the new API means you’re up to date on how OpenGL is and should be used in the real world. If you’re looking to work in the games industry, for example, that’s just plain useful knowledge.

Some useful learning materials:

- [An Intro to Modern OpenGL](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html)
- [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](https://web.archive.org/web/20140209181347/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/)
- [OpenGL Tutorials](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/) for OpenGL ≥3.3

Comment: I guess I'll have to forget what I know and relearn everything then right?

Comment: @NathanWride: Don’t worry. It’s not really that big of a step. Check out the links I’ve added.