# OpenGL 2.1 and glBegin()/glEnd()

Tags: opengl, opengl-2.0

there are lots of OpenGL tutorials out there - I think more than 90% of them make use of glBegin()/glEnd() with vertices set between these two calls. Now I found some people telling me these functions are deprecated and no longer available in newer versions of OpenGL.

So: is this correct?

In my application I have to be compatible with OpenGL 2.1.

Comment: https://open.gl is a decent tutorial that uses core OpenGL.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, glBegin()/glEnd() methods are deprecated. [glDrawArrays](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) is a modern approach and it is available in OpenGL 2.1. Here is [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300569/opengl-glbegin-glend).

Also, I doubt about this 90% value.

Comment: "Also, I doubt about this 90% value." I've seen mostly outdated OpenGL tutorials too, so I think the number 90% is about true.

Comment: `glDrawArrays()` is much older. It was added in OpenGL 1.1.

Comment: Just to emphase how much older it is: OpenGL-1.1 was released in 1996. OpenGL-2 was released in 2004.

Comment: So the question is: is glDrawArrays deprecated or not?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes and no.
The spirit of OpenGL 2 and more is to no longer use immediate mode and fixed pipeline. From OpenGL 3, these are "deprecated".
But fortunately at the same time was recognize "[Legacy OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL)"  And [ARB compatibility](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/compatibility.txt) extension. So you do can use still use them (modulo some variations between OS about what is inside or not).