# GLSL shaders going black/transparent

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am trying to add some shaders to my glut scene objects.

At this time I am trying to implement "hello world" shaders
but when I use the default vertex shader, my objects dissapear.

shaders:

```
#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version " core\n" #shader
const char* vert = GLSL
(
330,

layout (std140) uniform Matrices {
        mat4 pvm;
} ;

in vec4 position;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = position;
    gl_Position = pvm * position ;
} 
);
```

```
const char* frag = GLSL
(
330,    

in vec4 color;

out vec4 outputF;

void main()
{
    outputF = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 1.0);
} 

);
```

Compilation shows no error:

```
Compiling shader : vertex shader
VERTEX STATUS:1
Compiling shader : fragment shader
FRAGMENT STATUS:1
Linking program
PROGRAM STATUS:1
PROGRAM ID : 3
```

Before calling glUseProgram:

[image]

After calling glUseProgram:

[image]

After calling glUseProgram without attach vertex shader:
[image]

CODE for rendering:

```
int opengl_draw_path_gl(rendered_path_t *p) {
    unsigned int num_vertices,j;
    unsigned int face_size;
    unsigned long i,num_elems;
    vect_t *a,*b;
    num_elems=p->num_prisms;
    num_vertices=p->prism_faces;
    face_size=num_vertices*2;
    a=p->data+2; // saltem punt centre primera cara
    b=a+face_size;

    glColor4fv(p->color);

    // dibuixem tapa inici
    _opengl_draw_path_terminator(num_vertices,p->data,a);

    // Dibuixem tots els prismes
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for(i=0;i<num_elems;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<num_vertices;j++) {
            glNormal3fv((GLfloat *)(a+j*2));
            glVertex3fv((GLfloat *)(a+j*2+1));
            glNormal3fv((GLfloat *)(b+j*2));
            glVertex3fv((GLfloat *)(b+j*2+1));
        }
        glNormal3fv((GLfloat *)(a));
        glVertex3fv((GLfloat *)(a+1));
        glNormal3fv((GLfloat *)(b));
        glVertex3fv((GLfloat *)(b+1));
        a+=face_size;
        b+=face_size;
    }
    glEnd();

    // dibuixem tapa final
    _opengl_draw_path_terminator(num_vertices,b,a);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not calling to glVertexAttrib anywhere, it is mandatory?

Comment: glBegin, glVertex, glNormal, etc are the **very old** OpenGL fixed-pipeline. All of them are incompatible if you use a OpenGL **Core** Profile (as you set in the first line of your shaders).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I recommend you, to read a tutorial about [vertex array objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial2:_VAOs,_VBOs,_Vertex_and_Fragment_Shaders_(C_/_SDL)).

But, since you are drawing with [`glBegin`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) and [`glEnd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300569/opengl-glbegin-glend), which is [**deprecated**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300569/opengl-glbegin-glend), you have to use [compatibility mode shaders](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/185969-glBegin-glEnd-with-custom-shader-effect). You have to use the deprecated built in uniforms [`gl_Vertex`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/attributes.php) and [`gl_Normal`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/attributes.php), according to the OpenGL commands [`glVertex3fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml) and [`glNormal3fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glNormal.xml).

Adapt your code somhow like this:

```
#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader
```

Vertex shader:

```
const char* vert = GLSL
(
    110,

    varying vec4 position;
    varying vec3 normal;

    void main()
    {
        position    = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
        normal      = normalize( gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal.xyz );
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    } 
);
```

Fragment shader:

```
const char* frag  = GLSL
(
    110,

    varying vec4 position;
    varying vec3 normal;

    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 1.0);
    } 
);
```